# Java: how to represent characters not containing white spaces as words?

Tags: java

If I have a file containing random characters e.g:

```
sdo8kd      oko   ala la654
```

`"sdo8kd"`, `"oko"`, `"ala"` and `"la654"` would be considered words.

How can I represent a word not containing white space characters specifically using the method `Character.isWhitespace(c)` where c is the character being checked to see if it is white space.

Comment: What do you mean represent? you want to extract the words into an array?

Comment: @KunLun representing by counting how many words are found or put into an array, just a way to know they are words

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split(regex)` from `String` and put into an `array`, after that do what you want with it.

```
String sentence = "sdo8kd      oko   ala la654";

String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");

for(String word : words){ 

    System.out.println("'" + word + "'"); //'sdo8kd', 'oko', 'ala', 'la654'

} 

System.out.println(words.length); //4
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"

boolean isAlphaNumeric = s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");

a-zA-Z all latin letters (lower and upper case)

0-9 all digits

[a-zA-Z0-9]+ at least 1 or more characters inside brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to split the words even any number of space is in between.
You can use

```
 "sdo8kd      oko   ala la654".split(" +");
```

This will return String[] with values "sdo8kd", "oko", "ala" and "la654"